# MongoDB BI Connector

Tags: mongodb, tableau-api, business-intelligence, connector

I'm trying to connect Tableau Desktop 10.3 (windows 7) to MongoDB (redhat 6.5) using the MongoDB BI Connector, but it keeps resulting in this error on Tableau:

Tableau Error:

[image: Tableau Error]

On the other hand, when running the BI connector on the server side it gives a warning:

---

```
2017-05-17T11:06:45.635+0300 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for mongosqld.
```

---

I can't figure out where is the problem! When the database was running on the same machine with Tableau Desktop, there was no problem.

Comment: What does `Show Details` tell you?

Comment: Kindly please check it in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

[The "show details" content as in the screenshot below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l76OL.png)

Comment: Well, it says "unable to connect to *MySQL*".

Comment: It's trying to connect to the MongoDB BI Connector but I don't know what does it mean with the MySQL!

Comment: Then the ODBC connection you are using might link to a MySQL database instead of a MongoDB. Try checking the configured ODBC connections on your desktop.

Comment: "The connector is a separate process that takes a MongoDB database and maps the document schema into a relational structure that is then held in MySQL."

Comment: Which is good, still, something is not correctly configured there. With this new information I suppose that MySQL is not accessible from your desktop via your ODBC connection. Maybe wrong username/password or a firewall?

Comment: It's working now, the problem was the --addr option in the mongosqld command.

Comment: Now, it connects to mongodb and gets the databases but no collections are retrieved resulting in this error:                                                  
2017-05-17T16:30:34.558+0300 F NETWORK    [conn2] dispatch error: ERROR 1064 (42000): parse sql 'SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COMMENT, TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_SCHEMA FROM ( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND ( TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' OR TABLE_TYPE='VIEW' ) ) TABLES ' error: syntax error at position 202 near tables

Comment: Maybe your MySQL version is not the required one? The statement works fine with me on version 5.6.36